# Grasping the concept of UEFI vs. Legacy BIOS

Tags: boot, bios, uefi

I have done some reading but I am yet to understand some core elements about UEFI and legacy BIOS.

I understand that UEFI is the new software that replaced the long-used BIOS.

What I do not understand is this: People say that I should install W10 on my computer using UEFI mode but also say that the mode you **install** an OS and the mode you **run** the OS are different. What does it mean?

Comment: Good primer: https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/ — "also say that the mode you install an OS and the mode you run the OS are different" that ... doesn't make much sense, do you have a source for that claim? I suspect it's missing some context.

Comment: Hello @Bob. I think it means this: For exapmle you installed W10 in legacy BIOS mode but you can run it in UEFI mode. Is it possible? I have an Acer Aspire VX15 that came pre-installed with endlessOS Linux and I had to install W10 later on by myself but I never checked if what I did was in a specific *mode* to be honest. Just opened BIOS/UEFI(whichever it was) with F2 and choose to boot from the installation USB. Can I detect in what mode I installed W10 from here?

Comment: You cannot install Windows with Legacy Mode enabled and then boot to it while in UEFI mode.  Are you using the MBR or GPT partition scheme?  In the context of Windows, if you are using MBR, then UEFI mode cannot be used and Legacy mode must remain enabled to boot into Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound Then I am assuming that I have indeed installed it with UEFI in my own case because I just checked the UEFI interface and it said my boot mode was UEFI and option to turn secure boot off was grayed out.

Comment: I asked for the source of that claim, not what your interpretation of it is. Because on its own it is entirely nonsensical. Where do "People say ... that the mode you install an OS and the mode you run the OS are different"?

Comment: @Bob Well you said *that ... doesn't make much sense* so I just tried to help out with that because I don't care about verifying the source (which I don't remember the exact address of anyway) but about the accuracy/legitimacy of this information.

Comment: Secure Boot is an optional feature of UEFI, the fact it is grayed out, tells me you have actually legacy mode turned because Secure Boot cannot be enabled/disabled with Legacy support turned on.  **So go by which partition scheme you are using instead.**

Comment: @Ramhound Right next to secure boot option it says **Boot Bode: UEFI** though. How do I check the partition scheme?

Comment: Also, Secure Boot option is set to enabled. But I can't interact with it. AFAIK, secure boot can not be set to enabled if it was legacy. But I can be wrong.

Comment: I am shocked Acer sells any device where Secure Boot cannot be disabled, again its an optional feature of UEFI, and it's required to be able to disable it to sell Windows machines.  Seems strange Acer would have two classes of devices.  Do you have an EFI partition?  Typically 100MB-350MB FAT32 partition.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes. I do have an EFI partition in the SSD. I think it requires one sets a password in UEFI/BIOS before secure boot settings can be altered.

Comment: At this point the only conclusion I can draw is that you have incorrectly paraphrased someone else, and/or dropped a lot of important context. Therefore, this question is impossible to answer. It has nothing to do with verifying the source and everything to do with getting enough information to make the question answerable.

Comment: For example, the line you want explained could be taking into consideration UEFI emulation layers that can run on top of a legacy BIOS. It could be talking about non-Windows OSes. It could be talking about fallback bootloaders that can handle both firmware types. It could be talking about how booting in a different mode from installation actually results in a boot failure. It could also simply be completely wrong. Without more context than that little paraphrased snippet, there's no way to tell what was originally meant — and the paraphrased snippet alone doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Bob I don't bring the source in because I really don't recall the exact address but it was some post on a Microsoft or acer support forum and I'd trust you, a 39k rep user of this site, over them. I recall it was pretty much identical to what I asked though. It wasn't some article explaining the whole concept so there wasn't a lot of context to drop. If you say that the statement, with the way I paraphrase it, is wrong, then it is good enough for me to call it wrong.

Comment: @Bob So as long as I can boot into Win10 with UEFI showing **Boot Mode: UEFI** and the disk having EFI partition I can say that Win10 is installed in UEFI mode and NOT in legacy mode, right?

Comment: “I think it requires one sets a password in UEFI/BIOS before secure boot settings can be altered.“. This isn’t a requirement to disable Secure Boot

Comment: @Ramhound For acer-specific case I mean.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment [Bob](https://superuser.com/users/117590/bob) provided a link to [UEFI boot: how does that actually work, then?](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/). I recommend you read that carefully, although lengthy, it is well written and clear.

> **also say that the mode you install an OS and the mode you run the OS are different.**

This looks like nonsense, or at least, very poorly expressed.

### Old PCs

Old PC's had firmware that duplicated the functionality of IBM's BIOS firmware initially designed in the 1980's for use with pseudo 16-bit CPUs with less than 1MB RAM and, eventually, with hard disks which were initially about 5 MB in capacity. This BIOS firmware provided functions that the early operating systems (e.g. PC-DOS, MS-DOS, DR-DOS, etc) actually used to access the hardware peripherals (screens, disks, etc). Another part of the BIOS was responsible for starting the "bootstrap" process that ends with the operating system running. Eventually, improvements in processors, hard-drives and other hardware developed beyound what the BIOS could handle. At that point operating systems stopped relying on the BIOS to communicate with hardware, instead having their own native "drivers" in software.  The BIOS firmware's primary role was then mostly to do with getting the boot process underway.

A BIOS firmware typically expects to work with hard disks that are formatted and partitioned according to a scheme often referred to as MBR (after Master Boot record). This sort of firmware cannot understand a GPT disk.

### Modern PCs

The firmware in any recent PC will be UEFI firmware. That is, the firmware will conform to the UEFI specifications.

Such firmware is generally used in conjunction with "disks" that are formatted and partitioned according to the GPT standards.

### Backwards Compatibility

As far as I know, the UEFI standards do not say anything about what firmware should do when the PC has connected to it some MBR disks as well as or instead of GPT disks.

In practise most firmware that is built on UEFI standards also implement a means of understanding MBR disks and of using the BIOS method for starting a bootstrap process. This may be disabled by default. If enabled it means the UEFI firmware may automatically add MBR disk partitions to the list of boot targets that are tried in turn when attempting to boot.

### Consequence

In principle you could use a UEFI compliant firmware to boot some GPT compliant removable medium that contains an installer that formats and partitions a hard disk using MBR that is subsequently booted using the UEFI firmware's BIOS-compatibility bootstrap modes.